# How to check for a valid session in JSF application?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Before I explain the situation, I'll preface it by saying that the application I'm working on is old, outdated, needs to be rewritten, etc. but the company I work for doesn't care and is just looking for a quick bandage to this problem. Also, I'm just some random dude who they gave this app to and, despite knowing next to nothing about all this, they somehow consider me the subject matter expert.

I have a .xhtml page that users go to in order to pay bills. We use SiteMinder to control access to the application, and through this there has been set a two hour inactivity timeout limit for the application. However, we have recently implemented some new payment features from a third party vendor that make use of modal windows. If a user sits on this .xhtml page for an hour and fifty nine minutes, invokes the modal window (via a button click), and goes to complete various actions in the modal, then when they're done the third party vendor considers the action successful (since they are unaware of our timeout) but we do not receive any responses from them since the session has timed out on our end. This is a problem, because users can schedule future payments, and if we do not get a response from the vendor, we have nothing to store in our database which we eventually use to trigger the scheduled payment.

How can I determine if the user's session is still valid when they click to invoke the third party modal window? Here's what one of the buttons looks like:

```
<p:commandButton id="makePaymentButton" 
    value="Make Payment" onclick="makePayment(/*args*/);"
</p:commandButton>
```

Basically, instead of immediately invoking the modal window, I want to first check and ensure that the user's session is still valid. Since is there is not page navigation or server interaction when this button is clicked, the modal simply renders whether or not the user's session has expired.

Comment: Ian, I laughed out loud when I read your first paragraph.  I know exactly what you are talking about...

Comment: "How can I determine if the user's session is still valid when they click to invoke the third party modal window?" - but in your own example the session is still valid at this time (1h 59m), so this won't help. I thought the problem is that the session becomes invalid while the user is filling out the 3rd party dialog.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov - I actually thought about this this morning when lying in bed before my alarm went off. You're right - this would not solve my problem completely. I'd only be ensuring that the session was valid at the time the user invoked the modal. So now I'm left wondering how to avoid their session dying.

Answer (score 4):

If you use standard render Kit use :

```
<h:commandButton id="makePaymentButton"
                 value="Make Payment" 
                 actionListener="your action listener which may return an exception if the session control fails">
    <f:ajax onevent="makePayment(/*args*/)" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you use Primefaces use "oncomplete", "onsuccess" :

```
<p:commandButton id="makePaymentButton" 
                 value="Make Payment" 
                 actionListener="your action listener which may return an exception if the session control fails" 
                 onsuccess="makePayment(/*args*/)" />
```

Then, in the actionListener you can get the session :

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

Caution : the session reference might be null, then check what you need with it.

Dont forget to place `<f:view transient="true"> ... </f:view>` in order to disable the automatic creation of a JSESSIONID.

Comment: Good creative suggestion!

Comment: The ajax submit will likely create a new session itself, which may be what OP ultimately wants, but not what he's asking. Also, if this implies that `onsuccess` being triggered depends on actionListener throwing exception, then this is wrong.

Comment: getSession(false) doesn't create a session if it doesn't exist. For the other commenr about onsuccess, I'll check later, but I did that way in the past.

Comment: Maybe it's oncomplete checking arg.validationFailed ... I will have to check my old projects.

Comment: `getSession(false)` is irrelevant - the session would get created before that by the JSF impl.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov : yes, you are right. I forgot that. So my solution cannot work based on pure JSF. Thanx for pointing that. Maybe the use of  `<f:view transient="true">` can do the thing. This prevent creating a session when not needed.

Comment: As @VsevolodGolovanov pointed out above, my original request didn't account for the fact the session might end while the user is in the modal. Would this solution not only validate the current session, but also "renew" it so it's valid while the user completes the modal actions?

Comment: @IanW., you may want to touch the session if it's still valid, but you'd generally won't be fine with a new session because you probably need some data that was in the old session. Your JSF views will be expired too for one thing...

Comment: "Dont forget to place <f:view transient="true"> ... </f:view>" - he started the question by explaining how he inherited an old application. I really doubt he can just shove `transient` there. It would break the logic.

Comment: Without the full page code, it's difficult to tell that `transient="true"` is suitable or not. The first question was about `<p:commandButton>`, so I guess he can modify the JSF page.

Answer (score 2):

To know if the session is still valid, you'd need to ask the server. But you have to be careful, so that your "asking" request wouldn't automatically create a new session itself. The most surefire way is to ditch JSF altogether and create a simple Servlet.

```
public class CheckSessionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            // no session, let's respond 404
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            // session exists - return a succesful status
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
        }
    }

}
```

Do an AJAX POST request with JS to this servlet, and then act on the request outcome.

In order to prevent session timing out while the user if filling out the 3rd party dialog, you may want to touch the session to bump its timeout:

```
        } else {
            // session exists - bump timeout & return a succesful status
            session.setAttribute("someUnusedAttribute", 123);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
        }
```

And if the session is expired then you can refresh the page (with JS) to allow user to start anew. Or show a simple message to user, explaining that the session is gone and he needs to start again.

You can do all this without touching the legacy JSF stuff.